# Can someone show me an example using packDirRecur from Codec.Archive.Zip

Tags: haskell, zip

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    createArchive (Path "outPath.zip") (packDirRecur Store mkEntrySelector   (Path "/home/Documents/test"))
```

With this code get the following error:

```
src/Main.hs:39:60:
Couldn't match type ‘Path.Abs’ with ‘Path.Rel’
Expected type: Path Path.Abs Path.File -> ZipArchive EntrySelector
  Actual type: Path Path.Rel Path.File -> ZipArchive EntrySelector
In the second argument of ‘packDirRecur’, namely ‘mkEntrySelector’
In the second argument of ‘createArchive’, namely
  ‘(packDirRecur
      Store mkEntrySelector (Path "/home/Documents/test"))’
```

How do I get mkEntrySelector to generate an Absolute path?

Comment: Looks like you're on an old version of the `zip` package. I think this code should work without modification on the current version

Comment: Ahh you're right! Thank you very much! @BenjaminHodgson

Comment: Happy to help 